# How to add feature crop image using intent on android camera?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, camera, crop

I try to make app android for crop image using intent on android camera and then save result crop. I follow [this](http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/simple-android-photo-capture/) tutorial to make camera capture, but I don't know how to add feature crop using intent and save result crop for that.

Answer (score -1):

we use this library https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop for crop image from camera or gallery
you can see this library [sample](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop/blob/master/example/src/main/java/com/soundcloud/android/crop/example/MainActivity.java)
see method beginCrop and pass new File(_path) as parameter

Comment: Please share code/logic to solve the exact problem described in the question.

Comment: do you know how to set the crop region height and width?? like blue highlighted crop region